# Which format strings allowed as a fallback?

Tags: c

Let's take the following five examples:

```
// OK, most correct
printf("%10.4hd XXX", (short) 2);

// OK, no warning
printf("%10.4d XXX", (short) 2);

// Error: [-Werror,-Wformat]
printf("%10.4hhd XXX", (short) 2);

// Error: [-Werror,-Wformat]
printf("%10.4ld XXX", (short) 2);

// Error: [-Werror,-Wformat]
printf("%10.4f XXX", (short) 2);
```

Why, for example, does the second one work fine, but the third, fourth, and fifth ones do not?

Comment: Lookup [default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) for variadic functions. `short` is promoted to an `int` when passed to `printf`, so the first two formats work.

Comment: @dxiv thanks. Why is that done out of curiosity?

Comment: Because the C standard says so. Other than that, one can only guess. Most likely, stacks based on the machine-word size (i.e. int) were common enough to justify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the expression `(short)2` is subject to the integer promotion rules before it's passed to `printf`. That means it becomes an `int`.

`printf` provides the `h` length specifier, but the value it consumes will be an `int`, not a `short` because in C there's no way to pass a short value directly to a var-arg function.

From ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 section 6.19.6.1.7 on the `h` length specifier:

> Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier
> applies to a short int or unsigned short int argument (the argument
> will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its
> value shall be converted to short int or unsigned short int before
> printing); or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a
> pointer to a short int argument.

The `%hhd` format string should also work for similar reasons. I guess the reason that clang warns for this one and not for `"%d", (short)` is that the latter is technically correct and there's a lot of C code that uses %d for printing shorts.

The `%ld` is probably always undefined behavior, but may or may not work in practice depending on whether `int` and `long` have the same representation (typically this would be if `int` and `long` are both 64 bits).

The `%f` is always undefined behavior. `%f` expects a double argument (not a `float`, since floats are always promoted to `double` when passed to a var-args function), and you've given it an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

From [this site](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/int/sx11c.html):

> When a function with a variable-length argument list is called, the
> variable arguments are passed using C's old ``default argument
> promotions.'' These say that types char and short int are
> automatically promoted to int, and type float is automatically
> promoted to double. Therefore, varargs functions will never receive
> arguments of type char, short int, or float.

`printf` is a function with a variable-length argument list.  So when you pass in a `short`, it gets promoted to an `int`.

Now, even though `printf` will never receive a `short`, you can tell it that you started with one.  So `%...hd` tells `printf` that you passed in a short and it has been converted to an integer, and `printf` will try to do the right thing with it (convert it back to a `short` internally).

`%...hhd` works the same way but you use it when you pass in a `char` and it gets promoted to an `int`.  I guess that the compiler doesn't allow `%...hhd` in your case because it is smart enough to notice that you didn't pass in a `char` (you passed in a `short`).

`%...d` works because `printf` sees an `int` (and the compiler has decided that it doesn't mind that you didn't use `hd`).

`%...ld` and `%...f` don't work because you didn't pass in a `long` or a `float`, and a `short` doesn't get promoted to either of those types.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd recommend quoting from the C standard (or some version of it) rather than websites. Surprisingly much information about C on the internet (and in books) is inaccurate, and the standard is often quite understandable once you've found the right paragraph.

Comment: @PaulHankin, point well made and I see you have included the proper reference in your accepted answer, which is going to be helpful for future readers.  In this case I think the non-official info is okay though?

Comment: The online resource you've linked to is definitely top-notch high quality information. I just personally think more people should refer to the standard rather than read commentary. YMMV